# Strange C# behaviour. Setting one value affects two

Tags: c#

This has me stumped. The following constructor creates a new `Sector` instance, but changing the value in either `array1` or `array2` changes the value for both!

```
    public Sector (Vector3[] vertices)
    {
        Vector3[] array1 = vertices;
        Vector3[] array2 = vertices;

        array1 [0].X = 0;
        array2 [0].X = 1;

        Console.WriteLine (array1 [0].X);
        Console.WriteLine (array2 [0].X);
    }
```

The output is 1 for both arrays

```
1
1
```

Is this an intentional part of the c# language? What is the alternative?

Comment: You only have *one* array.  You're referencing it by multiple variable names, but there's only *one* array in memory.

Comment: array1 and array2 points to same array, vertices

Comment: All's fine. Both `array1` and `array2` point to the same object, which is `vertices`. So, the last assignment `array2[0].X =1;` directly modifies the `vertices` array, overwriting the change made by the previous line.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're being down voted to be honest.  Sometimes people confuse the purpose of down voting and do so when they perceive a question to be too "simple" which is obviously not the right reason to down vote.

Comment: @roryap Maybe because we should expect people to *search* for their problem first before posting a question?

Comment: @poke -- The OP obviously didn't know what to even search for.  Put yourself in his/her shoes, and come up with a search phrase.

Comment: @roryap To find the duplicate question target, I literally searched for *“two arrays both changed c#”*.

Comment: To address the duplicate hate, I was unaware this was a consequence of passing an array to a function. I was thinking more along the lines of a Vector3 issue, or the nature of c# constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are references so calling `array1 = vertices` doesn't copy the value but instead sets them to point to the same object. Thus you only have one array.

If you want two, then duplicate the arrays, for instance:

```
Vector3[] array1 = vertices.ToArray(); //ToArray duplicates the contents as an array
Vector3[] array2 = vertices.ToArray();
```

Comment: Or [`Array.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The OpenTK Vector3 class has no such function, but thanks I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the arrays you reference above are simply references to the vertices array. So, a change in either array will result in a change in the vertices array.

You would need to clone the vertices array, if you wish to avoid this referencing issue.